# want to make all poygons have z values as 0

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon

I have polygons which stores different z values as vertices in Arcgis. I want that all z values must be equal to zero.
How can I make this possible??
[image: Zvalues]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. Here the answer, I created an empty not z aware feature class and loaded data to this from existing shapefile.

Answer (score 3):

one way is to Export your feature class to another feature class using let's say, Feature Class to Feature Class tool and then in the Environment Settings, set the "output has z values" to Disabled. Then re-run feature class to feature class and set the "Output has Z Values" to **Enabled**.

[image]

Comment: this does not work because when I import the new feature class to cityengine, z values are displayed

Comment: do you want them (Zs) to be 0 or completely dropped off? if you want them removed set "output has Z Values" to ***Disabled***

Comment: Yeah ı tried this option too. But this time cityengine does not import shp file because it has no z values. It must have z values but all of them must be equal to 0

Comment: You are right. Check the edit answer